# I am trying to send an email to myself when an error happens from filling out the php form

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email to myself when an error happens from filling out the php form instead of doing Print="Sorry an error happened"

```
$error = "ERROR HAPPENED".$order."\r\n";
$error_email = mail($to, $subject, $error, $headers2);
$mail = @mail($email, $subject, $confirmation, $headers2);

if ($mail) {
    header("Location: http://www.test.com" );
} else ($error_email);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: don't suppress errors with `@`. it's VERY bad coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using brackets after the else.

```
if($mail)
{
    header("Location: http://www.test.com");
}
else
{
    mail($to, $subject, $error, $headers2);
    echo $error;
}
```

And you were never using echo $error so the error couldn't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little unclear - and it helps if you ask a question...

However, I'd suggest using a logging framework for this, such as [log4php](http://phpfunk.com/php/log4php-example/); this includes an email option, so errors can get mailed to you, or you can write them to disk, or the OS log file.

Please be aware that email is totally insecure - it's easy to intercept them, and they are not encrypted. I hope you're not sending sensitive data in the $order variable.

Finally, your code is probably not doing what you want it to.

```
$error = "ERROR HAPPENED".$order."\r\n";
```

Build the error string (assuming $order is nicely printable).

```
$error_email = mail($to, $subject, $error, $headers2);
```

Send an email to $to. $error_email is now a boolean value.

```
$mail = @mail($email, $subject, $confirmation, $headers2);
```

Send an email to $email. Suppress errors. $mail is a boolean.

```
if ($mail) {
    header("Location: http://www.test.com" );
```

if the mail was sent successfully (to $email), redirect the user.

```
} else ($error_email);
```

If the mail was not sent successfully, not sure what you're trying to do...

It's not a good idea to tie your application logic to the random "did I manage to send an email" success.